# GitHub markdown indent hanging indent

Tags: github, markdown, indentation

I am trying to make a webpage using github. But I got stuck when trying to make a hanging indent

I want to make a reference list using apa format. (In Normal Text, Not in Code)

```
 A., B., & C., D. (2020, August 1). Name of the paper. Name of the paper Name of the paper
      Name of the paper Name of the  paper. Journal of ABC. Retrieved from
      https://doi.org/1.1.2.2.2./deew/37.4.433
```

I have been looking around, but I could not find a way to do this.

Finally, this is what I found

```
A., B., & C., D. (2020, August 1). Name of the paper. Name of the 
paper Name of the paper Name of the paper <br> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;Name of the  paper. Journal of ABC. Retrieved from 
https://doi.org/1.1.2.2.2./deew/37.4.433
```

Which produce the following

A., B., & C., D. (2020, August 1). Name of the paper. Name of the paper Name of the paper Name 
             of the paper Name of the  paper. Journal of ABC. Retrieved from 
             https://doi.org/1.1.2.2.2./deew/37.4.433

But I think this is not a very efficient way to do. I wonder if you have any better ideas? Thanks!

Please let me know if you need more information. I am still trying to learn github.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the late response but this is for others with the same problem

The hanging indent that you want is somewhat the handling that you see after a list item and in the next line adding spaces before the text

```
1. List item itself
(space)(space)Hanging indent that is handled to make nice multiline list items
2. Next list item
```

Is is usually not possible in markdown itself. In HTML+CSS you can do this:

```
<p style="padding-left: 2em; text-indent: -2em;">
  (a) in relation to an exempt payment service provider 
  mentioned in subsection (1)(a), means any of the following 
  payment services:
</p>
```

But is is not always that you can use the CSS in Markdown supported HTML.

Some of the solutions have been explored [here](https://serial-comma.com/blog/posts/2020-09-13-hanging-paragraphs-in-markdown.html)